# Copying an image from the internet and pasting it results in a CID attachment style image

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, email-client, attachments

I am having an issue where if I copy and paste an image from the internet on a virtual machine, and paste it to an email on a virtual machine, it is adding it as a CID attachment, instead of a linked image.  I have even tried inserting the information using an html import option, but had the same issue.  The only way around this that I have found was to copy the image from my local machine, and then paste it to the email client on my virtual machine.

Does anyone know why this would happen?  It seems like backward functionality.  It seems like if the RDP session was messing with the copy and paste functionality, it would happen when trying to go from the local machine to the virtual machine, not from virtual machine to virtual machine.I have also tried a console session on the virtual machine, but no luck there either.  I have also inspected the data on the clipboard before pasting, and it has the url in the clipboard, not some weird CID attachment information.

NOTE: I must have it go from virtual machine to virtual machine, as I am running an automated test on that machine.

From virtual machine browser to virtual machine email:

```html
<p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;line-height: 1.15;">
  <img width="538" height="190" src="cid:2A4BFA79E9AC41F54CC8563084D305D8A90FEA7D@7E4A1A11" />
</p>
```

From local machine browser to virtual machine email:

```html
<p style="margin-top: 6.66px;margin-bottom: 6.66px;line-height: 1.15;">
  <img alt="Google" width="0" height="0" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some people that I know personally, it seems that when you copy an image on a RDP session, it actually copies the bitmap of that image, instead of the link(for a browser image).